# TypeScript: declare a type or an interface with a field that has an unknow name

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types

I have to declare an interface for a team object:

```
export interface Team{
  memberUid?: {
    mail: string
    name: string
    photoURL: string
  }
  startDate: Timestamp
  endDate: Timestamp
  agenda: Array<{
    date: Date | Timestamp
    title: string
    description: string
  }>
}
```

There will be several members Uids. I don't know how to declare it in TypeScript.

I tried:

```
[memberUid: string] : {
  mail: string
  name: string
  photoURL: string
}
```

But then TypeScript understand that all the fields in Team should have this structure.

What would be the correct way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49969390/9287029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying that I hate this structure.  If there's a way to rewrite your code to a more logical `Team` type, then do it.  But can it be done?  Yes, it can.  `Team` will have to be a `type` rather than an interface though, because interfaces can only have known keys.

Let's start by breaking it into pieces.

TeamBase defines the properties which are always present:

```
interface TeamBase {
  startDate: Timestamp
  endDate: Timestamp
  agenda: Array<{
    date: Date | Timestamp
    title: string
    description: string
  }>
}
```

UidProperties defines the contents of the unknown key:

```
interface UidProperties {
    mail: string
    name: string
    photoURL: string
}
```

Here's a utility type which can be used to declare a property based on the type of the key by using mapped types:

```
type HasProperty<Key extends keyof any, Value> = {
    [K in Key]: Value;
}
```

If the generic `Key` is a string literal then the only possible value for `K in Key` is that exact string, so `HasProperty<"myKey", string>` resolves to `{ myKey: string; }`

So now we need to define the type `Team`.  We know that it needs to include all of the properties of `TeamBase` and we know that there is some string key for which the value is `UidProperties`.  An important fact which was causing you problems before is that **this key cannot be one of the keys of TeamBase**.  So instead of using `string`, we use `Exclude<string, keyof TeamBase>`.

You can use `HasProperty<...>` to say that *every* string key which is not a key of TeamBase has a value of `UidProperties`, but I think it is better to use `Partial<HasProperty<...>>` which says that any of these unknown string keys could be `UidProperties` but could also be `undefined`.  When you access an unknown key, you probably want to double check that value anyways.

So our final type for Team is:

```
export type Team = TeamBase & Partial<HasProperty<Exclude<string, keyof TeamBase>, UidProperties>>
```

This works as expected.  Because we have allowed for the possibility that `uid` is undefined, you cannot access properties of `uid` without ruling out `undefined` via optional chaining with `?` or an `if` statement, etc.

```
function f1(team: Team) {

    const startDate: Timestamp = team.startDate;

    const uid: UidProperties | undefined = team['randomKey']

    const name = uid?.name;

    if ( uid !== undefined ) {
        const mail = uid.mail;
    }
}
```