# Typescript object with [key: string]: string | string[]

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a type defined as follows:

```js
type IColumn = {
  name: string;
  key: string;
  attributes: { [key: string]: string | string[] };
  shortable: boolean;
};
```

The only field of attributes that can be `string[]` is called `options`

So I would like to do something of the type:

```js
type IColumn = {
  name: string;
  key: string;
  attributes: { [key: string]: string ; options: string[] };
  shortable: boolean;
};
```

To avoid having to specify at each use of attributes whether it is `string` or `string[]`. But this does not work.

Is there a way to make it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type an object with known and unknown keys in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969390/how-do-i-type-an-object-with-known-and-unknown-keys-in-typescript)

Comment: I have tried this: 
```
type Attr = { [key: string]: string };
interface Attributes extends Attr {
  "!!!ExactlyOneOtherStringPropertyNoMoreNoLess!!!": string[];
}
```
But it does not work either. Same error: 
```
(property) Attributes["!!!ExactlyOneOtherStringPropertyNoMoreNoLess!!!"]: string[]
Property '"!!!ExactlyOneOtherStringPropertyNoMoreNoLess!!!"' of type 'string[]' is not assignable to string index type 'string'
```

Comment: I think tis answer is revelant https://stackoverflow.com/a/61434547/11637098

Answer (score 4):

Index signature like that requires that *every* possible value matches that signature. If you want that as a fallback you have to do an intersection with a `in string` signature:

```js
type IColumn = {
  name: string;
  key: string;
  attributes: { [key in string]: string }
    & { options: string[] };
  shortable: boolean;
};
```

Or using the nice aliases in the standard library:

```js
type IColumn = {
  name: string;
  key: string;
  attributes: Record<string, string> & { options: string[] };
  shortable: boolean;
};
```

If you think you might have this pattern in multiple places you can make a helper type like this:

```js
export type WithDefault<Default, T extends Record<string, any>> = Record<string, Default> & T;

type IColumn = {
  name: string;
  key: string;
  attributes: WithDefault<string, {
    options: string[],
    someFlag: boolean,
  }>;
  shortable: boolean;
};
```

Comment: First and second do not kork, I don't know why :(
Property 'options' is incompatible with index signature.
      Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'